# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01501: CREATE DATABASE failed ORA-01100: database already mounted

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, sqlexception

I made some MySQL java-jdbc code to create a database and add a few sample rows to it. I wanted to make this code work for oracle 11g also. So, I changed the connection URL in my code accordingly. But, now I am getting the error:

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01501: CREATE DATABASE failed
ORA-01100: database already mounted

I don't why am I getting this error. What does this mean "database already mounted" ? 
Please help me to fix this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: DDL syntax and semantics are where database implementations differ most.  Without seeing your DDL, nobody here is going to be able to help.  That said, the error means Oracle thinks the database already exists.

Comment: Using SQL Developer or any other means, how do I manually check if the DB exists ?

Comment: @fastboat - please post the relevant code that you're trying and as Jim Garrison said, your relevant DDL statements. Also, you might want to read this link for connecting using SQL Developer: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-may/o38sql-102034.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shutdown the database then start it in nomount stage then apply create database statement

```
     SQL>shutdown immediate;
     SQL>startup nomount;
     SQL>CREATE ........
```

Comment: Yes, that helped. Now I am getting a new error which I think can be fixed easily - java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the meaning of "mount" and "nonmount" ?

Comment: I  got a link with some info - http://www.dba-oracle.com/concepts/starting_database.htm